# Error when minify is enabled, but works otherwise

Tags: android, kotlin, aapt

As soon as I enabled minify, this issue started occurring.

```
-keepclassmembers class * { *** @{viewModel::onResendClick}(android.view.View); }
```

This method is a part of the viewmodel but this seems to be weird, I am not able to understand or debug this issue.

Comment: What issue started ocurring?

Comment: Hey @tenfour04 resolved the issue, actually there was a unused method declared in the XML, but finding that was difficult. Thank you for your help.